# Windows 2012 minimal interface

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

can a user run console application (similar to unix applications which use console mode only) on W2012 minimal interface install?

can user disconnect in a way that the app still be running?

or does he have to convert it into windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal interface doesn't function any differently than the full GUI as far as app lifecycle goes.

If you run an application in the context of a logged in session, it will terminate on **logoff**. If you are using RDP and **disconnect**, it will remain running as long as that RDP session is still active. If you have an app that you want to always be running including after a reboot before any user logs in, you should find a way to run it as a service.

Comment: thanks Ryan, that what i thought. just to make sure we are on the same on the main point - if the app outputs text to the console - it wont be any problem right?

Comment: Nope, shouldn't be a problem.